# Is ashwagandha (ginseng) allowed in the UK and US?

Tags: usa, uk, customs-and-immigration, transit, health

Ashwagandha (Indian ginseng) is a herbal product I regularly use. I will be travelling (only transiting) via London and then USA on my way to Peru soon. Does anyone know if this is banned/illegal in UK and USA? Can my bag be held up if this is found?

Comment: For the UK, you can check https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/list-of-banned-or-restricted-herbal-ingredients-for-medicinal-use/banned-and-restricted-herbal-ingredients As for whether your bag can be held up if it’s found, well I’d say the chances are pretty high it would be (and it’s owner, I imagine). Is it legal to import into Peru?

Comment: For the US, here's the general link from US customs about herbal medicines (which includes herbs): https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1217/~/traveling-with-non-prescription-medicines%2Fvitamins%2Fhealth-supplements . Since it is a plant product, additional research will be needed for that angle.

Comment: Are you traveling with tea, capsules, or the unprocessed plant?

Comment: @Traveller, thanks for the UK link. I do not see it listed there. I tried all the alternate and scientific names. I am not sure about Peru yet.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas, thanks for the US link. I also see that Ashwagandha is available for purchase on Amazon.com in the USA. I am assuming this is a good indicator of it's legality in that country?

Comment: @MichaelHampton, I will be travelling with the dried root powder

Comment: I think it's probably fine, but as always you do need to declare it.

Comment: @RameshB - There's a difference between "legal in the US" and "you are allowed to import it into the US." Just because I can buy the supplement here doesn't mean that I can bring plant matter of unknown provenance in from overseas. This is why i mentioned that additional research from this angle is needed. At minimum I would declare it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, to quote Wikipedia "there is no conclusive clinical evidence that it is effective for treating any ailment" and it's completely unregulated.

USA: [Can I travel with non-prescription medicines, or other products such as vitamins and health supplements?](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1217/%7E/traveling-with-non-prescription-medicines%2Fvitamins%2Fhealth-supplements)

> Non-prescription medicines (also known as over-the-counter or OTC medicines), vitamins, herbs, and supplement products fall under the jurisdiction of the Food and Drug Administration (FDA). In general FDA will not object to the personal importation of those products, as long as:
>
> - The traveler is carrying the products in their possession (or in their luggage);
> - The amount being carried is an amount reasonably considered for personal use.

[How do airports differentiate supplements from drugs?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/106812/4188) is at interesting on this topic.

The UK is harder but if you review [Personal food, plant and animal product imports](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/personal-food-plant-and-animal-product-imports#exempted-food-products) there's nothing in there that would limit you so the final exemption would apply: any other food product not containing any fresh or processed meat or dairy and with less than 50% of processed egg or fishery products.